# How is the Quill.js link format implemented？

Tags: javascript, quill, react-quill

I can **click** an exist link and it will pop over a prompt, but I can not find the source code about how it's implemented
[see the image display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qmUf.png)

it's not in https://github.com/quilljs/quill/blob/develop/formats/link.js

**Version**: 1.3.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that should be the class "SnowTooltip". You can find it within the "quill/themes/snow.js".
Assuming you're using the snow theme.
If not have look into "quill/themes/bubble.js" -> class BubbleTooltip